# What does "Potato Cat" mean when you point this to a person?

Tags: word-usage, slang, internet

I saw this phrase many times on Twitter. But, I don't know the exact usage or meaning this phrase portrays. Can anyone please enlighten me with the definition you think is accurate! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You asked same question couple of hours a go, right? I provided you with the Urban dictionary link already.

Comment: duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/489473/what-does-potato-cat-mean

Comment: The link you provided aka the definition already got many dislikes so I don't think the definition validly answers my question @ubihatt.

Comment: @J.Doe that's a slang phrase. That's the reason l commented a link. Check your luck this time :)

Comment: Do you have any notion what it could actually stand for @ubihatt?

Comment: @J.Doe To me it sounds like a lackadaisical feline spending entire day in sedentary position. Like a couch potato.

Comment: @ubihatt You too? I think, I’ll string along with the conjecture this time. Good day! :)

Comment: Do you mean "too many dislikes" means the dislikes are bad?  Suddenly I'm confused. I frequently assume that the answer is bad, but maybe......just maybe.....there's another way to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

This phrase is due to the popularity of a card game designed by the online cartoonist known as "The Oatmeal - the game is called "Exploding Kittens" and is now commonly played in households with children from just pre-teen through teen ages - some young adults have also adopted this game.

Potato Cat is a specific category of card in this game, which is intrinsically useless on its own, having no specific ability or action assigned to it; however, when assembled with other Potato Cat cards, can be used to demand a card from another player's hand. I'd guess half the reason this is used in the context of photos is visual...